# Selecting from Oracle table and inserting into table on Informix server

Tags: oracle, informix

I have this code so far

```
declare cursor test is
select kontrolen_broj, datum, iznos, smetka, nazivnalogodavac, povbr,
       celplacanje, nazivprimac, embg, sifra, dokumentid,
       trunc(datum_isplata) datum_isplata, netstat, najavaid, postaid,
       logid, brojtransakcija, mesec, godina, trn
  from table1@oracle
 where datum > '26-oct-2016';
begin
for c in test loop
    insert into "table1"@informix ("kontrolen_broj", "datum", "iznos",
                  "smetka", "nazivnalogodavac", "povbr", "celplacanje",
                  "nazivprimac", "embg", "sifra", "dokumentid", "datum_isplata",
                  "netstat", "najavaid", "postaid",
                  "logid", "brojtransakcija", "mesec", "godina", "trn")
          values(c.kontrolen_broj, c.datum, c.iznos,
                 c.smetka, c.nazivnalogodavac, c.povbr, c.celplacanje,
                 c.nazivprimac, c.embg, c.sifra, c.dokumentid, c.datum_isplata,
                 c.netstat, c.najavaid, c.postaid,
                 c.logid, c.brojtransakcija, c.mesec, c.godina, c.trn);
end loop;
commit;        
end;
```

It gives me an error at the beginning of the line 7 (formatting will have altered line numbers):

```
ORA-06550: line 7, column 13: PL/SQL: ORA-00972: identifier is too long ORA-06550: line 7, column 1: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

I am trying to run this in `plsql`, with selecting all of this code in the SQL window.

Comment: What is the real name of `table1` in Informix? I guess it's not `table1`, but something longer than Oracle's limit (30 characters)

Comment: Unless you're running a really old version of Informix (as in, "hasn't been supported for a decade or more" old version), you shouldn't run into 'identifier too long' on a table or column name before you're using 128 characters (bytes).  The 'owner' or 'schema' name is limited to a mere 32 characters (bytes).  It is more likely that you're running into an issue with Oracle name lengths.